# Find most stable point of two array parallelly

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, data-structures

I have two arrays.

```
let arr1 = [32, 35, 25, 37, 40, 45, 42, 46, 44, 45, 49, 50];
let arr2 = [46, 55, 55, 56, 57, 64, 70, 71, 78, 85, 86, 97];
```

Now I want a "stable" index of both arrays. like what is the index when both arrays are most state?

For example from the given array I want.

```
let index = 8 // this is what i want
```

***Index 8 means from `arr1` the ist "44" and from `arr2` "78"***

### Let me define what I mean by `stable` here.

At least their one before element and one after element's difference is the least of both arrays. (Sorry for my bad explanation.)

Don't flag this question just comment on what you need to know, I will try to explain. [Please]

As recommended by @Nina Scholz

This is what i tried so far [not working]

```
let arr1 = [32, 35, 25, 37, 40, 45, 42, 46, 44, 45, 49, 50];
let arr2 = [46, 55, 55, 56, 57, 64, 70, 71, 78, 85, 86, 97];
let diff_arr1 = []
let diff_arr2 = []
let compare_arr = []

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    diff_arr1.push(Math.abs(arr1[i + 1] - arr1[i]));
}

for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    diff_arr2.push(Math.abs(arr2[i + 1] - arr2[i]));
}

for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    compare_arr.push(Math.abs(diff_arr2[i] - diff_arr1[i]));
}

console.log("Array 1")
console.log("Array 1 diff");
console.log(diff_arr1);

console.log("Array 2")
console.log("Array 2 diff");
console.log(diff_arr2);

console.log('compare_arr')
console.log(compare_arr)
let arr_temp = compare_arr.filter(function (value) {
    return !Number.isNaN(value);
});
console.log(Math.min.apply(Math, arr_temp));
```

Comment: you could go ahead and add some code, you tried. what is the wanted result of the data?

Comment: @NinaScholz done, please check again!

Comment: @NinaScholz it's not working code and the result also consists of useless information. But you can excute the code its console.log 's

Comment: please add the **wanted** result of the taks. how does the result look like?

Comment: @NinaScholz done, Please check

Comment: why `44` and `78`? what happens with the delta of both arrays?

Comment: @NinaScholz what do you mean by delta? difference between two arrays?

Comment: yes, how do you get the index or the values?

Comment: @NinaScholz I want 44 and 78 because see their pre-index and post-index's value they are too stable.  at the same time for both arrays.

Comment: see, 46, 44, 45 is more stable than 25, 37, 40. Right?

Comment: the delta around `44` is `1` and for `78`, it is `14`. how do they match? what is *stable*?

Comment: now in arr2, you may say that these values 55, 55, 56, are more sable than what i select (71, 78, 85,) this is because i want most stable for both array at same index.

Comment: @NinaScholz are my last two comments clear doubt?

Comment: As far as I understand, stability of index `i` is given by `Math.abs(arr1[i] - arr1[i - 1]) + Math.abs(arr1[i] - arr1[i + 1]) + Math.abs(arr2[i] - arr2[i - 1]) + Math.abs(arr2[i] - arr2[i + 1])`, with `i >= 1` and `i <= arr1.length - 2` and you're looking for the index with minimal stability. Is this correct?

Comment: ‘Stable’ has no common meaning in mathematics as you’re suggesting. Please give a formula or a mathematical description of what you’re looking for. Your examples and repeating that you want a ‘stable’ index are not making it clear what you’re looking for.

Comment: @jabaa That would be how I also expect ‘stability’ would be defined. However that definition doesn’t work for the first example: the pair 45, 85 would be the minimum there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the delta of the previous value with actual and actual and next value and take later this delta the get a minimum delta of both deltas.

The result is different from the wanted, because it take the minimum delta of both arrays.

```
                          v
 32, 35, 25, 37, 40, 45, 42, 46, 44, 45, 49, 50
NaN  13  22  15   8   8   7   6   3   5   5 NaN

 46, 55, 55, 56, 57, 64, 70, 71, 78, 85, 86, 97
NaN   9   1   2   8  13   7   8  14   8  12 NaN
```

```js
const
    getDelta = (array, offset) => array
        .map((v, i, a) => Math.abs(v - array[i - 1]) + Math.abs(v - array[i + 1])),
    array1 = [32, 35, 25, 37, 40, 45, 42, 46, 44, 45, 49, 50],
    array2 = [46, 55, 55, 56, 57, 64, 70, 71, 78, 85, 86, 97],
    delta1 = getDelta(array1, 2),
    delta2 = getDelta(array2, 2),
    result = [...array1.keys()]
        .slice(1, -1)
        .reduce((a, b) => Math.abs(delta1[a] - delta2[a]) < Math.abs(delta1[b] - delta2[b])
        ? a
        : b
    );

console.log(result);
console.log(...delta1.map(v => v.toString().padStart(2, ' ')));
console.log(...delta2.map(v => v.toString().padStart(2, ' ')));
```

Comment: i do not know much about stackoverflow rewarding system. Actually i want to reward your answer. How to do?

Comment: you did it already by upvoting and accepting. more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: why? it is your question.